# SQL breaking my query where there is NULL value

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, insert, null

Here is my sql statement and the error I am facing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO COUNTRY(COUNTRY_CODE)
select unique(country_code) from AIRPORTDEMODATA where country_code IS NOT NULL;
  2  INSERT INTO COUNTRY(COUNTRY_CODE)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("KIT"."COUNTRY"."COUNTRY")
```

I am stating `where country_code IS NOT NULL` then why its saying `can not insert null`

Best Regards

**UPDATE**
Here is my country and airportdemodata tables:

```
SQL> desc airportdemodata
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 AIRPORT_ID                NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 COUNTRY                        NVARCHAR2(48)
 COUNTRY_CODE                       VARCHAR2(2)
 CITY                           NVARCHAR2(48)
 CITY_CODE                      VARCHAR2(3)
 AIRPORT                        NVARCHAR2(84)
 AIRPORT_CODE                       VARCHAR2(3)

SQL> desc country 
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COUNTRY_ID                NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 COUNTRY                   NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(48)
 COUNTRY_CODE                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
```

what am trying to achieve is that:
I want to get unique country_code and basis of these unique codes want to insert country from airportdemodata to country table

When and running this statement:

```
SELECT UNIQUE(COUNTRY_CODE)
FROM AIRPORTDEMODATA WHERE COUNTRY_CODE IS NOT NULL;
231 rows selected.
```

but when I running this statement then:

```
SELECT UNIQUE(COUNTRY_CODE),COUNTRY
FROM AIRPORTDEMODATA WHERE COUNTRY_CODE IS NOT NULL;
2905 rows selected.
```

I want to select country on basis of unique country code

Comment: Are these tables you have created yourself, or are you working within someone else's data model? I ask, because your airportdemodata table contains both the country and country_code columns (along with city/city_code and airport/airport_code columns), and this doesn't seem to be a good design. Typically, you would have a lookup table (e.g. your country table) that lists the details of that entity, and then you would have a column in other tables linked via a foreign key to the primary key of the lookup table. I'd expect your airportdemodata table to only have the country_code column.

Answer (score 3):

Error was thrown because of trying to insert NULL values in the `COUNTRY` column, not `COUNTRY_CODE`. You did not specify any value for `COUNTRY` column, an INSERT like that would insert NULL values in columns not specified in the statement.

Comment: you said well but how can I fix it

Answer (score 1):

Since all three columns of `country` are defined as `NOT NULL`, you have to provide a value for all three columns when you insert a new row. To load that table using distinct values from `airportdemodata`, you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO country (country_id,country,country_code)
SELECT ROWNUM,country,country_code
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT country, country_code 
          FROM airportdemodata 
         WHERE country IS NOT NULL AND country_code IS NOT NULL)
```

*This assumes that your `airportdemodata` always consistently pairs the same `country_code` with `country`.* If it doesn't, you'll have to do some aggregation or `ROW_NUMBER` work to select the proper `country` for each `country_code` if the latter is intended to be a natural key. But if your data is clean the above insert should work for you. Also you have a `country_id` column that requires a value. You could generate a sequential value through several means. For initial one-time load, the `ROWNUM` technique here would suffice. For ongoing inserts, you'd probably want to create a sequence and use that.

Comment: Thanks. your select statemetn is showing `2791 rows selected` whereas there is 231 unique country_code. My language is not English and having problem to explain. I want to select country on basis of these 231 country code

Comment: @Java_Beginner, Check your SQL and make sure it is exactly what I showed (make sure you included the `DISTINCT` keyword and didn't add any additional columns to that query block). Look at the data returned and see if you see duplicate country,country_code combinations. You shoudn't

Comment: Your provided query is right but the problem is distinct countries are 2791 and distinct country_code are 231 that is right and I want to insert data on basis of country_code not country but country on basis on country code

Comment: @Java_Beginner, If you have multiple (roughly 10 each!) `country` values for each `country_code`, how are you going to decide which `country` value to use? Sounds like dirty data. Once you decide the logic for picking the right one, I can help you with how to implement that using the `ROW_NUMBER` function, as I mentioned in my answer. But you may need to build your own mapping manually using some industry standard code list rather than derive it from a table that is so messy.